# How to set NSPredicate to look for fields different than nil?

Tags: swift, nspredicate

I'm trying to fetch fields in CloudKit that are different than nil and, also, that has a specific phone number (at the same time, obviously). But I'm having a hard time trying to do so... That is my code:

```
let predicate = Predicate(format: "phone == %@ && careTakerId != %@", tel, "")
```

If exists, it prints a "User exists" and it's printing it every damn time! Can anyone tell me if I'm doing the *predicate* right? Thank you

Comment: Describe your issue more clearly. I don't understand what you want to say with _If exists, it prints a "User exists" and it's printing it every damn time!_ . If your `predicate` generates unexpected result, show an example data and what you expect with that data.

Comment: I have a Record Type User in CloudKit, and it has a field phone and another one careTakerId. What I want is to look for those who was a phone number equals to *tel* and a careTakerId different than nil. But my issue is that even those Users who have a nil careTakerId are being printed

Comment: I see I will post something you should try as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it by doing the following:

```
let predicate = Predicate(format: "phone == %@ && careTakerId != ''", tel)
```

If you try with *!= nil* Xcode will crash and say it's not a valid predicate!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try this one:

```
let predicate = Predicate(format: "phone == %@ && careTakerId != nil", tel)
```

This may be useful for you:

```
let predicate = Predicate(format: "phone == %@ && careTakerId.length > 0", tel)
```

(The latter becomes false when `careTakerId` is `""` or `nil`.)

Comment: I tried them both but none of them seems to work for me... The first one gives me this error:  `'Invalid predicate: phone == "2133925574" AND careTakerId != nil (Error Domain=CKErrorDomain Code=12 "Invalid right expression in <careTakerId != nil>: <nil> is not a function expression"`

The second doesn't crashes but the predicate also doesn't filter properly, but thanks for your attention anyway

Comment: Sorry, I have been missing that you are using `Predicate` with CloudKit. I'll report when I find anything useful.

Comment: I got it! I was able to check if its different than nil by doing the following: `let predicate = Predicate(format: "phone == %@ && careTakerId != ''", tel)`

Comment: Oh, you have made it. I'm very happy to hear that. Please write a correct answer, before someone see my jamming noise.